# how to find overridable methods in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

`public class test2 extends ListActivity {
}`

eg:i want to find what are the methods in ListActivity that can be overridden ..what is the short key find this in eclipse.. how the method can be brought through eclipse intellisense that is suppose method  onListItemClick with certain parameters that can be overriden in listactivity ..how can it be brought through intellisense..or how can it be automatically generated through eclipse 
eg:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);



}
```

Comment: it made sense....your answer is wrong...check Slothsberry's answer...tats the right one...

Comment: Uh, I didn't post an answer :) I just posted a comment which requests for clarification because your question title and question body were confusing and conflicting with each other (basically, your English is pretty hard to understand). Great that Slothberry's answer did it for you. Have a good day further.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Source > Override/Implement methods

Accessible via right click, menu bar (alt+s), alt+shift+s

ykaganovich points out another way, which is faster for overriding a single members. Override/Implement allows multiple members to be overridden through a single action.

Answer (score 13):

If you put the cursor between methods (where the new method declaration will go) and hit ctrl-space, you get a list of all the methods that you can override.

Comment: from a coding perspective, id say this is a much better answer as its typical of what you would be doing when writing code. the dialog approach is really clunky

Comment: I've always tried to write `@Override` first, and then start write `public void on...` to find all possible overridable methods starting with `on`, which never have worked. Turns out it is as easy as you say in your answer!! *banging head*